# My HP laptop keeps telling me sounds is used by another application?

Tags: laptop, audio

My laptop will not play any music/videos. It keeps telling me that audio is being used by another device, but I have nothing else opened. I've tried getting on YouTube and Pandora, and nothing. I've tried testing the audio and still nothing. I've had no problems with this issue until now, and I can't think of what I could've done to cause this. Has this happened to anyone else?

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the speaker icon in the bottom right tray > Playback devices. What do you see? I'm guessing that there are multiple devices with audio playback capability, such as HDMI connected devices. With some audio playing and the volume up, 1) take note of the current default device (has a check mark) 2) go one by one and set as default (right click). If that didn't work, undo it. Right click on any item and make sure that "show ..." are both enabled. Any devices showing as disconnected that should not be?

If this did not help, next look into the drivers and audio settings. Short answer, find the settings that will fix the problem (e.g look for another audio icon, such as Realtek or look in the control panel) or reinstall the drivers. It's possible that something recently installed has changed the settings or broken your system. In the settings, there is usually a "test audio" feature you can try.

Last bit of advice. Going back to the system speaker icon, look into each of the other options there. Volume control options and open volume mixer are worth checking out. From the volume mixer, you can change the device as well. If you go back to playback devices and double click on the device, there are many options and a test feature under the advanced tab.